Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.0.aar to match attributes (Flutter)
[[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/FyXF8U6V.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/BHA1Vyxz.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/JYa53T2C.png)
ERROR:C:\Users\Appspedia.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2d8d9d0b1a50fd8ec2138a902767b2b0\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.0-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.8.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Appspedia.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2d8d9d0b1a50fd8ec2138a902767b2b0\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.0-runtime.jar.
> Error while dexing.
Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.8.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Appspedia.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2d8d9d0b1a50fd8ec2138a902767b2b0\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.0-runtime.jar.
> Error while dexing.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
this is the complete error
I've adde
dexOptions {
preDexLibraries false
}
in build.gradle
and
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core: 2.8.0'
but problem not resolve
all my dependencies are uptodate
I also try to clear project and rebuild it

Try to upgrade your gradle version. Gradle 8.2 works for me.
buildscript {
ext {
    kotlin_version = "1.9.0"
    gradle_version = "8.2.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}    

You may also need to add the dependency
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'


Yes it work, Thankyou so much!!
